# WCF exception stack trace information gets swallowed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I've looked into this issue for nearly a day now, off and on, and it's a real head-scratcher. Our WCF service doesn't log enough information when exceptions occur. In fact, when I debug it, Visual Studio doesn't even break on the errors unless I tick the 'Break On Thrown' debugging option, as if they're being caught somewhere else, but I can't figure out where.

Even stranger, I've now worked out that while this issue plagues both my localhost and all our deployment environments, a colleague's local environment does not have this problem. This is what I see when an error is thrown on my machine - note it has no stack trace or line numbers that might help identify the source of the issue:

```
2016-12-13 22:53:27,093 [21] ERROR Redacted.WcfUtilities.ExceptionHandler - Exception caught at application level
System.NullReferenceException: test
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.TaskMethodInvoker.InvokeEnd(Object instance, Object[]& outputs, IAsyncResult result)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeEnd(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage7(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage6(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

In contrast, my colleague gets this juicy information in his log file:

```
2016-12-13 22:51:33,340 [15] ERROR Redacted.WcfUtilities.ExceptionHandler - Exception caught at application level
System.NullReferenceException: test
  at Redacted.AlsoRedacted.FurtherRedacted.<RedactedMethod>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\...filename.cs:line 169
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
  at Further.UpThe.Stack.<RedactedMethod>d__143.MoveNext() in C:\...ADifferentFile.cs:line 625
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.TaskMethodInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.TaskMethodInvoker.InvokeEnd(Object instance, Object[]& outputs, IAsyncResult result)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeEnd(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage7(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

I know, the WcfUtilities.ExceptionHandler seems the obvious culprit, but I've checked and it's pretty harmless, plus it's used in both environments without suppressing log information in one of them.

What could account for this difference? Is it IIS, perhaps? I'd have thought most of the settings for that would be defined in our config files that we both share via source control.

Comment: Try a compare with your colleague's machine.config and web.Config. I would start there

Comment: One way to ensure your IIS is same as your colleague is to do IIS Deploy -> Export on his machine (produces a zipfile) and IIS Deploy -> Import this zipfile on your machine. Do an IIS Deploy -> Export on your machine as a backup first. You will need to have Web Deployment tool installed (free Microsoft download). We've used this technique at work to ensure that IIS servers in dev & test environments have the same settings.